# Field not required but if user entered a value it must be meeting some rules (vuetify rules)

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am trying to enter a validation for a field that accept url, the field not required but if user entered a value it must meet url regex.

so I tried the following code

```
<v-text-field height="34px" v-model="website" single-line outline placeholder="http://"  :rules="urlRules"></v-text-field>
```

this attribute :rules="urlRules" refer to a bulk of rules that I give in my vue object

```
 urlRules: [
        v => !!v || 'required',
        v => /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi.test(v) || 'Please enter a correct URL to your website'
      ],
```

I want to change the validation in the rule object to make it not required but if user entered a url it must be correct

Answer (score 4):

This is how I manage to validate non required fields with Vuetify:

```
urlRules: [
    (v) => ( !v || YOUR_REGEX.test(v) ) || 'Please enter a correct URL to your website'
  ],
```

Check the `!v`. I am validating first, that if nothing is passed, will trigger a `true` value, this means, will not be required. But if something is passed, will check your regex or whatever expression you want to place.

There are other options, like an `if else` inside the rules, but i prefer this (prettier).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below

```js
urlRules: [
    v => (v && v.length > 0 && !YOUR_REGEXP.test(v)) ? 'Please enter a correct URL to your website' : true
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by maintaining separate validation functions as follows:

```
export const emailFormat = v =>
  /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(v) ||
  "E-mail must be valid";

export const emptyEmailFormat = v => {
  if (v && v.length > 0) {
    return /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(v) ||
      "E-mail must be valid";
  } else {
    return true
  }
}

emailRules = {
    isRequired: this.question.mandatory ? required : true,
    emailFormat: this.question.mandatory ? emailFormat : emptyEmailFormat
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I got this idea after posting this question

I used a regex that accept an empty value with the pattern I want

here is what I used

```
urlRules: [

        v => /^$|[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi.test(v) || 'Please enter a correct URL to your website'
      ],
```

so if there is a better answer share it with me plz